# Red updating text in VID using reactive method

Tags: red

```
Red [needs: 'view]

num: ["1^/"]
k: num/1

view [
     size 600x600
     txt: text 30x50 k
     ar: area 300x400 "" focus on-change[
         txt/size: ar/size
         len: length? split face/text newline
         either (len - face/data) > 0 [
               append num append form (len + 1) newline
               face/data: len
         ][
               remove back tail num
               face/data: face/data - 1 
          ]
          txt/text: form num
     ]
     do [ar/data: 0]
]
```

This Red program contains a "text face" and an "area face". The text face contains a vertical list of serial numbers. When a newline is added in the area face, the serial number will increase as per number of lines. And when a line is removed in the area face, the serial number will decrease as well.

This is using a non-reactive method. Is there a reactive approach to do it?

Comment: For code that works, there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ; best way (I think) is to post there and link to it from gritter.im/red/help channel

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you we're looking for the [`react`](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/reactivity.html#_react) function. The reactive framework was introduced in [this blog post](http://www.red-lang.org/2016/06/061-reactive-programming.html) and there is a very similar example of converting an example using `on-change` to its reactive version.

Anyhow, I was reading a lot lately about Red, and I was looking for an first exercise; My `to-list` implementation could be improved probably, but the view declaration is more compact now:

```
Red [needs: 'view]

to-list: function [text][
    ; converts text area string to list of numbers separated by newlines
    txt: copy text
    append txt "dummy" ; handle empty lines
    len: length? split txt newline
    x: copy ""
    repeat i len [ append x mold i append x newline]
]

view [ 
    size 600x600 
    text 30x600 react [
        face/text: to-list text-area/text
    ]
    text-area: area 300x400 ""
]
```